# Why NFS shows 100% but actual disk usage is some MB only

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, mount, nfs

We have an issue with one of the NFS as its showing 94% usage as per df but actually some 10 BM only used.

```
# df -h |grep lv-new-1401
cbjserver:/f04780/lv-new-1401    10G  9.4G  650M  94% /var/lib/myapp/lv-new-1401
```

And see what is inside the directory.

```
# pwd
/var/lib/myapp/lv-new-1401
# du -sh .
9.7M    .
```

Anyone experienced same ?

Comment: Opened, but deleted files.

Comment: @IporSircer 
Oh, but nothing found in ps as well.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

Client's `df` reports usage of the NFS server's *filesystem* which holds the exported directory. The directory itself may contain less data. I think this is your case.

Comment: Might be the case. I need to check with the storage team it seems.